# Generating a sample using inverse CDF method in python

Tags: python, quantiles

How can I generate 1000-element sample using inverse CDF method? It should be easy but I'm a complete beginner. I know what it is mathematically but I don't know how to implement it in Python

Answer (score 2):

First, generate a sample in the interval $[0,1]$. Use numpy's `random.rand()` function for instance. Second, transform the sample with the help of the inverse CDF function. [Scipy](https://www.scipy.org/) provides these functions under the signature `distribution.ppf(quantile, parameter1, parameter2,...)`.

Example using normal distribution with $\mu=3$ and $\sigma=2$:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

q=np.random.rand(1000)
result=stats.norm.ppf(q,loc=3,scale=2)
```

If the distribution of the inverse CDF function is not implemented in Scipy you will have to derive it yourself or find it in the literature. [Sympy](http://www.sympy.org/de/) can be useful with more complex derivations.